# Mysql complex issue on a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question

suppose there are two tables

```
customer 

Cid  name 

CustomerImage

ImgId  Cid
```

here `Cid` is the foreign key

I know if I want to see the all the images of all the customer I will write

```
select customer.Cid, Customer.name , CustomerImage.ImgId from customer INNERJOIN CustomerImage where customer.Cid= CustomerImage.Cid
```

this shows the list for every image with the customer id and name

what should I add in this if I want to show all the images of one Cid in one column

```
Cid   image name
```

so the image column should contain all the ImgId for the customer

Comment: Well look for group_concat : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Or you can use prepared statements for "select images for customer with id=id" and fetch results. It may be faster than grouping ids into string and splitting it from your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to group all images in one row for each customer, you can do it with the `group_by` clause  and `group_concat` function in MySQL:

```
select c.Cid
     , с.name
     , group_concat(ci.ImgId separator ',')
from customer c
join CustomerImage ci on c.Cid = ci.Cid 
group by  c.Cid
        , c.name
```